# Discriminant of Polynomials (Galois Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, positive-characteristic

So I'm reading Dummit and Foote and they define the discriminant of $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ by
$$D=\prod_{i<j}(x_{i}-x_{j})^2$$
and the discriminant of a polynomial to be the discriminant of the roots.

They say that a permutation $\sigma \in S_{n}$ is in the alternating group $A_{n}$ iff $\sigma$ fixes the product $\sqrt{D}$.

> It follows by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory that if $F$ has characterstic different from 2 then $\sqrt{D}$ generates the fixed field of $A_{n}$ and generates a quadratic extension of $K$.

I am confused where characteristic $2$ comes into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the field $F$ is having $2$ for characteristic

$$\sqrt{D} = \prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$$ is preserved by all permutations as $-1=+1$.

Comment: Another way to say this is that permutations still change the sign of $\sqrt{D}$ correctly, it's just that a characteristic $2$ field can't see it.